# Synchronizing changes in Local DB and Main DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am suppose to Synchronize my Local DB with Main DB so when User logs in, Local DB is suppose to be synchronized with Main DB. Any changes User makes on Local DB are suppose to be reflected on main DB right away.

What would be the best (smartest) way to implement this?

Comment: MySQL Replication.Off topic.

Comment: DB Architecture should be SLAVE and MASTER Configuration. MASTER DB will be reflected and synced with SLAVE.